# Queries about inapp purchases in BlackBerry using paymentSDK

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have used the paymentsdk.jar in my project and am successfully able to connect my application to BlackBerry app world. The goods in my vendor portal are in draft mode and having NON-CONSUMABLE(1 time purchase)license type. On button click, I am calling the purchase function and when I complete paypal payment, its successful. Please note, my money did not get deducted.However when I click again to purchase the item, I am again entering the payment method. Some of my queries are :

1) Can we purchase an item when it is in DRAFT status in vendor portal?

2) When an item is purchased, does app world change its status as purchased since license type is NON CONSUMABLE? if YES, how long does it take to reflect

3) What are the different status types for GOODS ? Right now its in DRAFT.

Thank you

Comment: have you implemented blackberry in-app in your app or used option on vendor portal

Comment: I used Vendor portal method

Comment: http://devblog.blackberry.com/2012/06/selling-android-digital-goods/

Comment: I know all the things thats mentioned in the link you just gave, I have queries after that. If I want to support different screen devices, where is the provision to upload multiple .COD files in RELEASES.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of your first question - You can purchase an item in draft mode(for that you have to create a sandbox account).
If you purchase an non consumable item, The app world change its status to purchase.